# Jquery Mouseover effect doesn't work inside <button> element in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, mouseover

I'm working on my 1 page portfolio, but am stuck on this 1 bit of jquery.  I have 2 pseudo buttons that are just on-page links.  I am using jquery to dynamically add an empty  inside of those links, then toggle the opacity on those spans such that I appear to be animating the button.  My overlaying span image is lighter in color so it sort of glows.  I have a contact form on this page and I wanted to add the same button effect to the submit button.  This is working in IE and Chrome, but NOT in FF.  In FF, the mouseover never seems to be triggered on the  element nested inside the button.  It *does* work as planned on the links, so I am not sure what makes this element fail to comply. The text-indent is also *not* working in FF so that the actual button text is disappeared away in favor of the background image.

here is my markup:

```
<div id="buttons" class="clearfix">
    <a id="worksbutton" title="<?php _e('View My Work');?>" class="scroll" href="#works"><?php _e('View My Work');?></a>
    <a id="contactbutton" title="<?php _e('Contact Me');?>" class="scroll" href="#contact"><?php _e('Contact Me');?></a>    
</div>
```

and later i have the following button that i'd like to behave the same way:

```
<button type="submit" id="sendbutton1">Send</button>
```

here is the jquery i am using to add an empty span tag inside of each link and the button (with an opacity of 0), followed by the code i have for animating the opacity of the span to 100% on mouseover.  this works great for the links.

```
$('#buttons a, #sendbutton1').each(function() {
    var button = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("<span></span>" + button);
    $(this).children("span").css("display","block").css("opacity","0");
  });

$('#buttons a span, #sendbutton1 span').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
  if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
    // animate opacity to full on mouseover
    $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, "slow");
  } else {
    // animate opacity to nill on mouseout
    $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, "slow");
  }
});
```

and finally the CSS i am using on the links and on the button

```
#buttons a{
height: 61px;
width: 161px;
display:inline-block;
text-indent: -9999px;
background: url(images/sprite1.png) no-repeat;
position: relative;
text-align:center;
}

#buttons a span {
background:url(images/sprite1.png) no-repeat;
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
height:inherit;
width:inherit;
z-index:100;
}

a#worksbutton{
background-position: -161px 0;
}

a#worksbutton span{
background-position: -161px -61px;
}

a#contactbutton{
background-position: -322px 0;
}

a#contactbutton span{
background-position: -322px -61px;
}


#form-container button#sendbutton1{
    display: block;
    background: url(images/sprite1.png) no-repeat left -2px;
    border: none;
    height: 61px;
    width: 145px;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

button#sendbutton1 span {
    background: url(images/sprite1.png) no-repeat left -61px;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    z-index:100;
}
```

This one is driving me a little batty.  Is this a bug or am I missing something?  Could really use your fresh eyes on this one.  Thanks!

EDIT: in the comments on this post: http://stopdesign.com/archive/2009/02/04/recreating-the-button.html i found the solution to the firefox "phantom padding" on my button.

```
button::-moz-focus-inner { padding: 0; border-style: none; }
```

huzzah!  of course then i found that IE will choke on animating transparent images and render an awful-looking black border, so I have cheated and assigned a white background color (which will work since my background is white, but defeats the purpose of transparent PNGs and limits me in my bg choice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why the span element inside the button isn't firing an event on hover, but you should easily be able to work around it by just looking for the event on the button itself. Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/fVkSX/)!

Also, I've modified your code a bit, `.wrapInner()` is made just to do what you are doing at the beginning of the script. And there is no reason to use `.live()` in this situation:

```
$('#buttons a, #sendbutton1')
.each(function() {
  $(this).wrapInner("<span></span>");
  $(this).children("span").show().css("opacity","0");
})
.bind('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
  var span = $(this).children('span');
  if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
    // animate opacity to full on mouseover
    span.stop().animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, "slow");
  } else {
    // animate opacity to nill on mouseout
    span.stop().animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, "slow");
  }
});
```

Comment: Wow!  Thank you!!  I haven't been able to get that to work for something like 2 days.  Have you checked it in Firefox?  There is still a very strange vertical and horizontal offset that doesn't exist in other browsers.  But otherwise, this is 97% perfect.  Thanks for the tip on wrapinner() too.